# Authenticating email through SMTP or DKIM

Tags: perl, smtp, sendmail, spf, dkim

I'm using Perl with the
[`Mime::Lite` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite)
to send email to my subscribed mailing list using
[*DomainKeys Identified Mail* (DKIM)](http://www.dkim.org/)
and
[*Sender Policy Framework* (SPF)](http://www.openspf.org/)
record:

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

my $host = 'mail.domain.com';
my $user = 'user@domain.com';
my $pass = 'password1234';

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $host, AuthUser => $user, AuthPass => $pass);
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From     => $from,
    To       => $to,
    Subject  => $subject_enc,
    Type     => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
    Data     => 'Hello everyone!'
);
$msg->send;
```

This works just fine, but the DKIM signature fails in Gmail (and presumably others).

However, when I send email without SMTP authentication:

```
use MIME::Lite;
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => $from,
    To      => $to,
    Subject => $subject_enc,
    Type     => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
    Data     => 'Hello everyone!'
);
$msg->send;
```

The DKIM passes fine.

So my question is: if I have successfully implemented both DKIM and SPF records on all my outgoing email, is it even necessary to use SMTP authentication to verify the sender of the email, or is piping to `Sendmail` with the appropriate headers sufficient to ensure best chance of delivery?

Answer (score 1):

Local authentication doesn't add much to the credibility of your messages, but also there's no harm in it. It will show up in your `Received` headers either way, and there's a distant possibility you might be marked down by spam filters for it (they'd probably be more interested in whether any hops were unencrypted, which is independent of auth).

That you used auth shouldn't make any difference to DKIM - but what will make a difference is where (and if) your DKIM signing takes place - for example if your local mail server signs but your remote one doesn't. Does the Mail::Lite package do DKIM signing itself? Or are you relying on your servers to do it? Your headers in received messages will show you what has been signed where, and they may also give you some clues about what exactly is wrong with your DKIM signature - it would be useful if you added gmail's headers to your question.

A separate concern is performance - submitting via a sendmail binary is relatively inefficient - all sendmail binaries do is open a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost anyway, so you may as well do it directly - this is what postfix recommends.

Comment: Relying on servers to add DKIM signature, but for some reason it doesn't do it correctly with mail sent from Mime::Lite. I can use another module DKIM::Mail::Signer to do it, but I'm starting to doubt the added complexity since it works OK without outgoing auth. I don't understand your concerns over performance. 'May as well do' what directly?

Comment: Send via SMTP to localhost rather than using sendmail to do the same thing but slower.